# Https клиент для WebGL билда в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужен клиент для отправки https запросов в WebGL билде или совет как его сделать.

[WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) не предлагать - он ужасен. Там как минимум нету keep-alive соединений, плюс он плох с https.

[UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) не умеет keep-alive.

Есть [плагин](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38367) для веб-сокетов, но уже год не обновлялся.

Для всех остальных у меня используется своё решение на базе сырых сокетов (C# TcpClient), но это пространство имён недоступно в WebGL билде.

Предложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) теперь можно использовать. В Unity 5.3 этот компонент был experimental namespace и работал через пень колоду.

В Untiy 5.4 класс перенесён в `UnityEngine.Networking` и вполне стабилен. На удивление ещё и keep-alive соединение поддерживает. Так что, для WebGL можно его использовать теперь (как минимум в Unity >= 5.4).

**Примечание:** для WebGL ваш сервер должен отправлять [CORS заголовки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Так же сервер должен поддерживать OPTIONS запросы.